# Sum of list elements and length of list in lambda calculus

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to make function for computing sum of list elements and length of list in lambda calculus.
Example of a list: `a := [1, 2, 3] = λcn.c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))`
`sum a` should return 6 and `len a` should return 3.

I wrote recursive versions:

```
len = λl.if (empty l) 0 (plus 1 (len (tail l)))
sum = λl.if (empty l) 0 (plus (head l) (sum (tail l)))
```

where if, empty, plus, tail are other lamda functions.

Then I did some trick with fixed-point combinator:

```
len = λl.if (empty l) 0 (plus 1 (len (tail l))) 
len = λfl.if (empty l) 0 (plus 1 (f (tail l))) len
len = Y λfl.if (empty l) 0 (plus 1 (f (tail l)))
```

where `Y = λf.(λx.f(x x))(λx.f(x x))`
Just the same for sum. So now I have non-recursive versions. But I can't get beta normal form using beta reduction here.
**I wonder if there is beta normal forms of these functions and how they look like.**

Comment: So when you say `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, are those meant to represent church numerals `λf.λx.f x`, `λf.λx.f (f x)`, `λf.λx.f (f (f x))`, etc?

Comment: @naomik yes, exactly

Comment: gallais offers a perfect answer for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These can be implemented much more easily given that a list is encoded by its own iterator:

```
a := [1, 2, 3] = λcn.c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))
```

means that a list is a function of two arguments: one to use on `cons` nodes and one to use at the end on the `nil` constructor.

As a consequence you can implement `length` by saying:

- ignore the value stored in a `cons` node and return `+1`
- replace `nil` with `0`

which translates to:

```
length := λl. l (λ_. plus 1) 0
```

which would expand to (at each line the expression in bold is being either unfolded or reduced):

```
length a
(λl. l (λ_. plus 1) 0) a
(λl. l (λ_. plus 1) 0) (λcn.c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n)))
(λcn. c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))) (λ_. plus 1) 0
(λn. (λ_. plus 1) 1 ((λ_. plus 1) 2 ((λ_. plus 1) 3 0))) 0
(λ_. plus 1) 1 ((λ_. plus 1) 2 ((λ_. plus 1) 3 0))
(plus 1) ((λ_. plus 1) 2 ((λ_. plus 1) 3 0))
(plus 1) ((plus 1) ((λ_. plus 1) 3 0))
(plus 1) ((plus 1) ((plus 1) 0))
(plus 1) ((plus 1) 1)
(plus 1) 2
= 3
```

Similarly, you can implement `sum` by saying:

- use `+` to combine the value stored in a `cons` and the result of evaluating the tail
- replace `nil` by `0`

which translates to:

```
sum := λl. l plus 0
```

which would expand to

```
sum a
(λl. l plus 0) a
(λl. l plus 0) (λcn.c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n)))
(λcn. c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))) plus 0
(λn. plus 1 (plus 2 (plus 3 n))) 0
plus 1 (plus 2 (plus 3 0))
plus 1 (plus 2 3)
plus 1 5
= 6
```

Comment: Responding to a now deleted comment: Do you mean `len := λl. sum (λc. l (λ_. c 1))`?

Comment: nice answer; i added the reduction steps to show that your `length` and `sum` functions work as the asker intends; i hope that's ok ^_^

Comment: Thanks @naomik, that looks great!